# Size function in Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, size, translation, implementation

I am attempting to translate this MATLAB code into Python. Here is the code:

```matlab
function snr_est = estimate_snr(R,r_m,x)

         [L N]=size(R);           % L number of bands (channels)
                                  % N number of pixels (Lines x Columns) 
         [p N]=size(x);           % p number of endmembers (reduced dimension)

         P_y = sum(R(:).^2)/N;
         P_x = sum(x(:).^2)/N + r_m'*r_m;
         snr_est = 10*log10( (P_x - p/L*P_y)/(P_y- P_x) );

return;
```

My question pertains to the size method. For the usage of size as is in the MATLAB code, MATLAB says that "it returns the number of rows and columns when `A` is a Matrix". I want to do the same thing in Python. I know that `a.shape` also returns the dimensions of the array. Can those then be accessed in the same way that the MATLAB code requires them in this function?

Comment: Not everyone that knows python will know matlab and vice-versa. Post a sample input/output or a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both MATLAB's `size` function and the numpy's `shape` property output dimensions in the same way.

For example, if `A` were a 3D matrix in MATLAB called that had 3 rows, 4 columns, and a depth of 5, `size(A)` would return `[3, 4, 5]`.

Similarly, in python if I had a 3D numpy array `B` with the same dimensions, `B.shape` would return `(3, 4, 5)`.

In the example you provided above, `R` is a matrix of dimension `L x N` and `x` is a matrix of size `p x N`. Assuming that the matrices (2D numpy arrays) you pass into your python function will be the same (i.e. `R.shape=(L,N)` and `x.shape=(p,N)`, MATLAB's `size` and numpy's `shape` will behave the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful!